# Merger simulation literature request

Tags: reference-request, merger-simulation

In an effort to empirically back up merger simulation models (which are rarely used in practice) I am trying to find 'old' papers, working papers, memos, etc. that have data on simulations people ran on mergers at that time. Using this information and the post merger information only available in the present I hope to see how effective merger simulation models were in estimating the post-merger economic effects.

If my request is still unclear [here is a paper by Craig Peters](http://econpapers.repec.org/article/ucpjlawec/y_3a2006_3av_3a49_3ai_3a2_3ap_3a627-49.htm) with the same goal.

Are you aware of any such references or collection of references that could prove useful?